# Error on insert data on rethinkdb via python

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

with following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import rethinkdb as r
import os
import configparser as c
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib3

config = c.ConfigParser()
config

config.read("etc/db.py")

conn = r.connect(config.get("DB", "host"), config.get("DB", "port"), config.get("DB", "db")).repl()
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
get = http.request ("GET", 'http://s1-it.ogame.gameforge.com/api/universes.xml')

xmldoc = minidom.parseString(get.data)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("universe")
id = []
href = []
a = 1
for s in itemlist:
    if a < len(itemlist):
        id.append("{ \"id\": \"" + s.attributes['id'].value + "\", \"href\": \"" + s.attributes['href'].value + "\" }, ")
    else:
        id.append("{ \"id\": \"" + s.attributes['id'].value + "\", \"href\": \"" + s.attributes['href'].value + "\" }")
    a = a + 1

data = "".join(id)

print(r.table("universes").insert([ data ]).run())

cursor = r.table("universes").run()
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

I have tried to parse a XML document and insert it into rethinkdb.

When I have launched python3 file.py I have seen following error:

Expected type OBJECT but found STRING

What is wrong in my script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert a string as a document when RethinkDB expect you to try to insert an object (dictionary in Python) or an array of objects.

You can solve this by just parsing the string into JSON.

```
import json

data = json.loads("".join(id))

print(r.table("universes").insert(data).run())
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm newbie of python and rethinkdb. I try tonight.

Comment: I have tried but I receive following error:

ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 58 - line 1 column 1380 (char 57 - 1379)